# Binding User Control Properties to ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have the following `UserControl`:

```
public partial class ConstraintBlock : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Constraint", typeof(Constraint)
            , typeof(ConstraintBlock));

    public Constraint Constraint { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler EditClicked;

    public ConstraintBlock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Constraint.ToString());
        if (this.EditClicked != null) this.EditClicked(this, e);
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML for it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Controls.ConstraintBlock"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="60" d:DesignWidth="500">
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Grid.Row="1" Click="btnEdit_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

A Constraint is a class defined as follows:

```
namespace MyApp.Classes
{
    public class Constraint
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ConstraintObject Object { get; set; }
        public ConstraintClause Clause { get; set; }
        public Nullable<ConstraintOperator> Operator { get; set; }
        public string Expression { get; set; }
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionTypeConverter))]
    public enum ConstraintObject
    {
        Expression,
        [Description("File Extension")]
        FileExtension,
        [Description("File Name")]
        FileName
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionTypeConverter))]
    public enum ConstraintClause
    {
        Contains,
        [Description("Does Not Contain")]
        DoesNotContain,
        Date,
        Length,
        Like,
        [Description("Not Like")]
        NotLike,
        Number
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionTypeConverter))]
    public enum ConstraintOperator
    {
        [Description("=")]
        EqualTo,
        [Description(">")]
        GreaterThan,
        [Description("<")]
        LessThan,
        [Description(">=")]
        GreaterThanOrEqualTo,
        [Description("<=")]
        LessThanOrEqualTo
    }
}
```

I then have the following ItemsControl in the UI:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="constraintStack" ItemsSource="{StaticResource constraintCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ctrls:ConstraintBlock Constraint="{Binding}" Grid.Row="2"
                                       EditClicked="ConstraintBlock_EditClicked"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

When I add a `Constraint` to the `constraintCollection` resource, the `ItemsControl` shows the `ConstraintBlock`, and also shows the "Name" binding in the `TextBlock` as the "Name" (property) of the `Constraint` I just added.

The problem is that when I click the "Edit" button and `btnEdit_Click()` is called, I get a `NullReferenceException` on the `MessageBox` line - somehow the `Constraint` property of the `ConstraintBlock` object is null, even though I have (attempted to) set this with `Constraint="{Binding}"` in the XAML for the `ItemsControl`.

What is wrong with this binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's difficult to say for sure. You haven't shown what the `Constraint` type is, nor have you provided the implementation for `ConstraintBlock_EditClicked`.

That said, the most obvious problem I see in your code is that you haven't implemented your `Constraint` dependency property correctly. You register the property, but your getter and setter have their default implementation instead of calling `GetValue()` and `SetValue()`, respectively. Without participating in the dependency property system, any time WPF attempts to use the property via the `DependencyProperty` value directly instead of through the property getter and setter, nothing useful will happen.

This is consistent with getting a `NullReferenceException`, assuming `Constraint` is a reference type. Since the dependency property's actual value remains `null` as far as WPF is concerned, you get the exception.

If my theory is correct, changing your property implementation will fix the problem:

```
public Constraint Constraint
{
    get { return (Constraint)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter - it works! Also, I added the definition of a Constraint class in for clarity.